# Как удостовериться что все визуальные изменения на странице завершены?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, puppeteer

Нужно удостовериться, что на странице больше не будет визуальных изменений (например коррекции высоты svg элементов), чтобы сделать её скриншот.

Есть ли какие либо глобальные события или флаги состояний того что javascript и react отработали?

Когда использую эмулятор браузера puppeteer, захожу на страницу и кликаю на определенный элемент, то если подождать 200 милисекунд то размер всех элементов всегда фиксированный. А если не ждать, то размер svg элементов на странице будет скакать в пределах 1-5 пикселей.

Comment: событие `onstart`, `onload`, `onloadend`.

Comment: Через события - никак. `load` вызывается только для конкретных элементов на которых вы его слушаете. когда загрузится весь динамический JS контент вы никак не узнаете. Единственный вариант - ставить таймаут. Есть еще правда [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), но в вашем случае от него особой пользы нет, все равно придется вместе с таймаутом использовать.

Comment: @hindmost, ШТА? Прочитайте про событие `onload`, причем тут `js`, это событие не обязательно вызывать через `js`, так как данное событие работает на документе, и когда документ загружен, он дает знать, что больше изменений нет, а раз есть `js` то, после загрузки документа вешать событие через `js` и контрить уже конкретно необходимые элементы, которые могут измениться.

Comment: Мне нужно сделать скриншот страницы, после нажатия на какую то кнопку на странице. Неизвестно что произойдет на странице, важно дождаться момента когда не будет никаких перерисовок элементов больше.

Comment: @And _а раз есть js то, после загрузки документа вешать событие через js и контрить уже конкретно необходимые элементы, которые могут измениться._ Так в этом как раз и проблема - таких "конкретно необходимых элементов" может быть 100500, и вы даже не про все из них можете знать (напр-р если они не вами создаются).

Comment: @hindmost, вы говорите ерунду, не может быть элементов. о которых не будем знать - это неправильно. Все элементы страницы должны контролироваться. По крайне мере можно взять самые главные элементы вида шапки. контента и футера. И это уже говорит о том, что мы сможем контролировать изменения этих главных элементов.

Comment: @And А может это вы ерунду несете? `load` вызывается _**только**_ для элемента, на к-ом повесили обработчик, на вложенные элементы это не распространяется. если вы слушаете `load` на каком-то "главном" элементе, вы не узнаете когда загрузятся вложенные ресурсы подгружаемые асинхронно (картинки, видео и т.п.), не говоря уже об элементах, создаваемых через JS. Для этого вам нужно вешать обработчик на _**каждый**_ такой вложенный элемент.

Comment: @hindmost, не готов согласиться... Любой измененный элемент в элементе , будет изменен родитель.

Comment: @And Похоже вы спорите о какой-то своей "сферической" ситуации. В react.js, к-ый использует ТС, весь контент загружается/рендерится _**после**_ срабатывания `load` документа. т.е. на момент рендеринга `load` уже сработало и больше не будет вызываться. повесить `load` на блок невозможно (только на `window/document/body`, фреймы и медиаресурсы). так что вы не сможете узнать _**когда именно**_ все отрендерилось.

Comment: hindmost правильно говорит, для любого SPA событие `onload` не является показателем окончания рендера. Он лишь показывает что все ресурсы загружены и успешно отрендерен первый фрейм, который содержит только один элемент `<div id="root">`. Даже более того Вы не можете отхендлить окончание рендера для любого одного компонента в реакте, что уж целое приложение. Поэтому только тайм-аут...

Comment: А в реакте или в js нет какого нибудь показателя что рендера больше не будет. Или например количество времени прошедшего со времени последних изменений во внешнем виде? 
А то мне по сути ставить таймаут по 200 мс для каждой проверки? Это сильно увеличивает время прохождения тестирования.

Comment: Нет такой возможности.

Comment: @hindmost, После запроса, когда он отработал, проверять какой был контент и какой теперь, можно при первом запуске страницу `сейвить` и потом сверять элементы по `DOM`, какой из элементов страницы был изменен, удален, добавлен. (делить каждый пройденный запрос и сохранять и потом сверять) Если без запроса, то это только на `js-коде`, функция будет в любом случае, а значит и после каждого обращения к функции, можно  будет в нужном месте проверить. (не может оно без ничего появиться, а если и есть, то в любом случае должен быть флаг успешного завершения).